# How to add new property in the json data without adding in the interface using typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I am trying to add new properties inside the josn data without adding in the interface. But i am not able to add it.So, How to add new properties in the json data. Is it possible or not?

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  data1: Candle[] = [
    {
      name: 'john',
      place: 'forest',
      phone: '124-896-8963'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jay',
      place: 'City',
      phone: '124-896-1234'
    },
    {
      name: 'Joseph',
      place: 'sky',
      phone: '124-896-9632'
    },
  ];

  foo() {
    const modifiedData = this.data1.map(d => {
      d.expanded1 = false; // error! 
      //~~~~~~~~~ Property 'expanded1' does not exist on type 'Candle'.
      d.expanded2 = false; // error! 
      //~~~~~~~~~ Property 'expanded2' does not exist on type 'Candle'.
      return d;
    });

    console.log(modifiedData);
  }
}
interface Candle {
  name: string,
  place: string,
  phone: string
}
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this, if you don't have access to the interface (or don't want to change it), is to extend the interface to have the new fields.

Comment: You could use `Object.assign()` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wey9Kw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz:Please add your answer with stackblitz

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking me to use a particular web IDE?  Like [stackblitz in particular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvejfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)?  Or are you just saying I should write up an answer because it meets your needs?  Help, I'm confused.

Comment: @jcalz: not working in stackblitz:  console.log(modifiedData);

Comment: Your stackblitz code is syntactically incorrect; you have a `const` inside a class body without a method.  You want me to fix that for you also?  Okay, [here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvejfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).  But that problem is with your example, not with my suggestion.  What should we do from here?

Comment: @jcalz: Got It. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really like to let you mutate the *type* of a value, and adding new properties to an object whose type isn't known to have them will give you a compiler error for good reason (this is quite likely to be a mistake).  One way around this issue is to use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which mutates its first argument by adding properties from the remaining arguments.  TypeScript's [call signature for `Object.assign()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/32b618c2d8f42948e7d6fa2e9b264079e30b5349/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L266) returns the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the input types, which means the output is known to have all the properties of all the inputs.

That means we can change your code to

```
const modifiedData = this.data1.map(d => {
  return Object.assign(d, { expanded1: false, expanded2: false });
});
/* const modifiedData: (Candle & {
expanded1: boolean;
expanded2: boolean;
})[] */
```

And now `modifiedData` is known to be an array whose elements are `Candle` objects with two extra `boolean` properties, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO8DCB7AtvFA7AplgLtAN4BQ00AJmPmAIwBc0SYWFIOA2gLrQC80HMuWJDh0LGDQ5GAcgBWKABZYZAGlHD44YNOgyAZigBOOCPjUby8Rdl0zaAJgAsAWgAcATgBs77wGYZDQBfdTFSMXIJKVkAKTAATwsI6C0wHVkkAEt8RNCI61tZR1dPH0c-J0CxEI1wiKi7GJQIHGsk-O07CABrXMsUm1wi518ffwcq4RryLgBuEiFDFAAKAEoRMWBsM2g0FApM-UycCgARajA+aHxFTIgAOioaWnu0MHhlij4APg2Ik3wAFcjFhoAB5ABGchwwHw90gEEyAHMsJ9VMRoDgAB7wFgUE4MaD6MAgFro7G41gnByMYmknDQIKrebVZkLTbbFDse4gFBI5Z7A5HE7nGhssQAegAVNAtlgdoLDsczhdGMtmKx2NAAGR-cgUvEExgQlBcnAsFnCA1Uig06Ams0W4KrbjQKUSoRBEhe3AAdzgiFQGFsBDW9yWaxImQIOCMxJ0TDxWrqDUYZiM0aReVS6Wg6cz2cGunzWCR3oWQA)